# Can I use an EF Core assembly DbContext in a .NET Framework app?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've got a large legacy ASP.NET MVC app that's running the .NET 4.8 Framework. It uses EF 6, but I'm trying to port this to EF Core by making another assembly, targeting .NET Core, and calling it from my existing app.

(I'm doing this because the entire app is enormous, and porting the whole thing to Core will be a huge project, so I'm picking it off in chunks.)

Visual Studio lets me add a reference to my new Core assembly, but when I try to use the `DbContext` from it, I get this error:

> Error BC30652 Reference required to assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=7.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' containing the type 'DbContext'. Add one to your project.

But when I try to add the reference, I get the error:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.8'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Is there any way to do what I need here?

Comment: The short answer is "No". The longer answer is that to my knowledge there isn't any "easy" way to migrate a .Net Framework app straight across to .Net Core. It was a bit of a pipe dream they pitched with .Net Standard but essentially dropped that with .Net Standard 2.1.  I have had some success "weaving" .Net Framework MVC /w MVC Core, being two web applications that hand off reasonably seamlessly with one another but this does come with challenges around things like authentication. It does require changes within the .Net Framework app...

Comment: ... and mileage will vary. It is highly dependent on how the existing web application is structured. For instance a lot of use of things like Session State can be a significant blocker. My advice is to look at what a minimum viable product system replacing a useful block of work looks like to give users an alternative new section of the application. Like a "Beta" version that grows and gets feedback while the original is still available. That often keeps interest and funding to see more of the system improved.

Comment: @StevePy: I'm not trying to migrate the app itself, I'm trying to make a new, native Core app and call it from my Framework app.

Answer (score 3):

.NET Framework 4.8 supports only .netstandard 2.0 and lower. It is not going to work with anything that targets only .NET 7. The latest version of EF Core that targets .netstandard 2.0 is 3.1.32.
In this example I connected .NET Framework 4.8 with EF Core 3.1.32

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Test
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("Test");
            
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
    
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbContext = new ApplicationContext();

            dbContext.Tests.Add(new Test()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid()
            });
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Code works");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [EF Core is deprecated on .NET Framework,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/) except `EF Core 2.1 will continue to be supported when used with ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET Framework only.`